# how do i add each different class when radio button checked

Tags: jquery

how do i add each different class when radio button checked??

this is my html code ?
plz help me

```
<fieldset class="default (Want to add Class here)">
<input type="radio" id="a1" >
<label for="a1">style1</label>
<input type="radio" id="a2" >
<label for="a2">style2</label>
<input type="radio" id="a3" >
<label for="a3">style3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tell us, what have you tried?

Comment: First of everything you are having syntax error in your html
it should be like this `<input type="radio" id="a3" />`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak No, that is necessary for XHTML or XHTML-valid HTML only. Self-closing elements are not part of HTML, nothing but syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See demo here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LXJt/)
in radio button **name** attribute use group that button

```
 <fieldset class="default (Want to add Class here)">
    <input type="radio" id="a1" name="radio_btn">
    <label for="a1">style1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a2"  name="radio_btn" >
    <label for="a2">style2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a3"  name="radio_btn">
    <label for="a3">style3</label>
    </fieldset>

$('input').change(function(){
    var a=$(this).attr("id");
  $('fieldset').attr("class",a);
  alert($('fieldset').attr("class"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the change event in [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/change/) as follows:

```
<fieldset class="default (Want to add Class here)">
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="red" class="a" />
    <label for="a1">style1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="black" class="a" />
    <label for="a2">style2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="gren" class="a" />
    <label for="a3">style3</label>
</fieldset>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').change(function () {
        // ...
        $(this).parent().addClass('class name');
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle to illustrate the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/ingenu8/RMAMG/)

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's not 100% clear but if you look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yawXd/

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
   $("fieldset").addClass("red");
});
```

Any time a radio button changes, you can add a class to the `fieldset`.

Now, I've added the alert for the `id` of the `radio` in case you wish to conditionally change the class on the `fieldset`.

Also, you should probably use a `class` for the `radio` buttons, and select via that - but more importantly, you should assign an `id` to your `fieldset` and use that to assign the `class`:

```
<fieldset id="fldSet1" class="default (Want to add Class here)">

...

$("#fldSet1").addClass("red");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set the name attribute of your radio buttons to the same value if they belong to the same group, so that when you select one, the others get unselected. Also, add an id to the fieldset (but you can also use the class selector if you prefer).

```
<fieldset class="default" id="aFields">
<input type="radio" id="a1" name="myRadioField" >
<label for="a1">style1</label>
<input type="radio" id="a2" name="myRadioField">
<label for="a2">style2</label>
<input type="radio" id="a3" name="myRadioField">
<label for="a3">style3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Then try this:

```
$('input', '#aFields').change(function() { $(this).parent().addClass("myClass"); });
```